# how can the if (){}else{} statement execute both outcomes

Tags: javascript

I want to create a basic search engine that searches students already existing in an array of objects by first name and last name and if it finds a student named that way enlist it on the page, and if it doesn't write on the page it doesn't exist. but when I have 2 people with the same first name, it gives me both outcome of the if statement. can someone help, please

```
    searchButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    userSearch = searchInput.value;
    for (i = 0; i < allStudents.length; i++) {
      student = allStudents[i];
      if(userSearch.toLowerCase() === student.firstName.toLowerCase() ||
      userSearch.toLowerCase() === student.lastName.toLowerCase() ||
      userSearch.toLowerCase() === student.firstName.toLowerCase() + " " + student.lastName.toLowerCase() ||
      userSearch.toLowerCase() === student.lastName.toLowerCase() + " " + student.firstName.toLowerCase()) {
        outputDiv.innerHTML +=  "<h2> Student: " + student.firstName + " " + student.lastName + "</h2><br>" +
                                  "Age: " + student.age + "<br>" +
                                  "Eye Color: " + student.eyeColor + "<br>" +
                                  "Hair Color: " + student.hairColor + "<br>" +
                                  "Programming Skills: " + student.programmingSkills
      searchInput.value = "";

      } else {
      searchInput.value = "";
      outputDiv.innerHTML += "<h2>The student you searched for is not in out database</h2>"
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: It is 100% guaranteed that *the same execution* of the `if` block *does not* result in also executing the `else` block.  You are very likely making a false assumption in your debugging.  Note for example that your `if/else` structure is inside a loop.  Perhaps it's executing *more than once* and producing different output in different iterations of the loop because the conditions are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to change your logic as you have two tasks:

- Find if the `student` exists
- Display `student`s if available else show message

You can use a variable (`found`) to keep track of whether any `student`s were found in `allStudents`, that way you won't have to worry about the `else` condition executing more than once

```js
let allStudents = [{
  firstName: "George",
  lastName: "A"
}, {
  firstName: "George",
  lastName: "B"
}]

searchButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  outputDiv.innerHTML = "";
  userSearch = searchInput.value;
  var found = false;
  for (i = 0; i < allStudents.length; i++) {
    student = allStudents[i];
    if (userSearch.toLowerCase() === student.firstName.toLowerCase() ||
      userSearch.toLowerCase() === student.lastName.toLowerCase() ||
      userSearch.toLowerCase() === student.firstName.toLowerCase() + " " + student.lastName.toLowerCase() ||
      userSearch.toLowerCase() === student.lastName.toLowerCase() + " " + student.firstName.toLowerCase()) {
      outputDiv.innerHTML += "<h2> Student: " + student.firstName + " " + student.lastName + "</h2><br>" +
        "Age: " + student.age + "<br>" +
        "Eye Color: " + student.eyeColor + "<br>" +
        "Hair Color: " + student.hairColor + "<br>" +
        "Programming Skills: " + student.programmingSkills
      found = true;
    }
  }
  if (!found)
    outputDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>The student you searched for is not in out database</h2>";

  searchInput.value = "";
});
```

```html
<input id="searchInput" value="George" />
<button id="searchButton">search</button>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange the check to see if it's found or not. You are outputting "that student was not found in our database" INSIDE the loop of students, so it's outputting that text even if another result (in the loop) WAS found. I have corrected that issue by moving the check (for if a student was found) outside of the loop and using a variable to track that. I also changed some things so that you aren't reformatting names toLowerCase() in every loop or having to locate a DOM element.

```
searchInput = document.getElementById("search_text"),
searchButton = document.getElementById("SearchButton"),
outputDiv = document.getElementById("outputdiv");
searchButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
   var userFound = false;
   userSearch = searchInput.value;
   studentLen = allStudents.length;
   outputDiv.innerHTML = "";
   for (i = 0; i < studentLen; i++) {
     student = allStudents[i];
     userSearch = userSearch.toLowerCase();
     var fn = student.firstName.toLowerCase(),
     ln = student.lastName.toLowerCase();

     if(userSearch === fn || userSearch === ln || userSearch === fn + " " + ln || userSearch === ln + " " + fn) {
       outputDiv.innerHTML +=  "<h2> Student: " + student.firstName + " " + student.lastName + "</h2><br>" +
                                 "Age: " + student.age + "<br>" +
                                 "Eye Color: " + student.eyeColor + "<br>" +
                                 "Hair Color: " + student.hairColor + "<br>" +
                                 "Programming Skills: " + student.programmingSkills
       searchInput.value = "";
       userFound = true;
     }
   }
   if(!userFound){
     outputDiv.innerHTML += "<h2>The student you searched for is not in out database</h2>";
   }
});
```

Working fiddle with HTML/JS both included:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ltkacgn4/